# Parameter 0 of constructor in .. required a bean of type org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, spring-jdbc

I have written a simple todo app (based on what comes in [apress pro spring boot](https://www.apress.com/gp/book/9781484236758) in which we use jdbc to deal with database ,in the repository we have the following code to deal with h2 database

```
package com.apress.todo.repository;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.apress.todo.domain.ToDo;

@Repository
public class ToDoRepository implements CommonRepository<ToDo> {
    private static final String SQL_INSERT ="insert into todo (id,\r\n" + 
            "description, created, modified, completed) values (:id,:description,\r\n" + 
            ":created,:modified,:completed)";
    private static final String SQL_QUERY_FIND_ALL = "select id,"
            +"description, created, modified, completed from todo";
    private static final String SQL_QUERY_FIND_BY_ID = SQL_QUERY_FIND_ALL +
            " where id = :id";
    private static final String SQL_UPDATE = "update todo set description ="
            +":description, modified = :modified, completed = :completed"
            +"where id = :id";
    private static final String SQL_DELETE = "delete from todo where id = :id";
    private final NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;





    public ToDoRepository(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {//HERE IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS
        System.out.println("hi masoud");
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }





    private RowMapper<ToDo> toDoRowMapper = (ResultSet rs, int rowNum) -> {
        ToDo toDo = new ToDo();
        toDo.setId(rs.getString("id"));
        toDo.setDescription(rs.getString("description"));
        toDo.setModified(rs.getTimestamp("modified").toLocalDateTime());
        toDo.setCreated(rs.getTimestamp("created").toLocalDateTime());
        toDo.setCompleted(rs.getBoolean("completed"));
        return toDo;
    };
```

and the following is my main spring boot application runner

```
package com.apress.todo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;


@SpringBootApplication
public class TodoInMemoryApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TodoInMemoryApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

but when I run the application using spring boot command line interface I will get the following error:
Description:

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in com.apress.todo.repository.ToDoRepository required a bean of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate' in your configuration.
```

there is nothing more explained in the book .

Comment: Could you share your properties file? Do you have the starter `spring-boot-starter-jdbc` as dependency? AFAIK Spring Boot initiates the JdbcTemplate when detected the connection.

Comment: You should use JDBCTemplate to access to your database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what examples in your book look like but I'll try to help you. Look, you declare a field `private final NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;` . Somehow you hope to spring to initilize it. In order for it you have to declare `@Bean` with `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` type in `@Configuration` class or create a `@Component` class extending `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`. Or extend `NamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport` and get via `getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate();`

Actually with your example, adding `spring-boot-starter-jdbc`

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and adding properties e.g

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
```

should solve this problem according [tutorial](https://www.devglan.com/spring-jdbc/working-with-springboot-namedparameter-jdbctemplate)

Comment: so I had to actually set application.properties in my example to create a bean.thanks,you helped me a lot.